# Android - Formatting a TextView

Tags: java, android, formatting, textview

I created a simple word search which works in normal Java where it prints out a 2D array of the letters. Everything is perfectly inline and looking nice, but when trying to turn this into an android app, none of the letters are inline.

My code is the following:

```
TextView wordGrid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordSearch);  
String grid = "";

    for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++)
    {
    grid += i + "   ";

        for(int j=0; j<matrix.length; j++)
        {
            grid +=  matrix[i][j] + " ";
        }
        grid += "\n";
    } 

    wordGrid.setText(grid);
```

The main.xml document contains the following attributes for 'wordSearch'

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/wordSearch"
android:layout_width="400px"
android:layout_height="400px"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_x="41dp"
android:layout_y="25dp" />
```

I can't get it to display all of the letters inline. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Aside from the point, but raw String concatenation is (relatively) expensive. When building strings like this, it's generally better to use `StringBuilder`, adding new portions to the string with `append()` and getting the result with `toString()`.

Comment: post your, matrix please

Comment: Thanks for the info on StringBuilder, I've taken your advice!
By 'inline' I mean that, if you imagine a wordsearch all of the columns are 'inline'. By this I of course mean the 2D array. Inline was possibly a bad word to use, I apologize.

The code for my Matrix is below.

Comment: The code for my Matrix is 
public static String matrix[][] = new String[10][10];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
wordGrid.setText( Html.fromHtml( grid ) );
```